# Sendkeys not sending multiple words

Tags: selenium

When I pass a single word, e.g. "Gopi", to a text box using `sendKeys()`, it works. When I try to send multiple words like "Gopi Kingston", the value disappears immediately.

```
String value = "Gopi Kingston"; // this does not work
Driver.findElement(By.id("searchbox")).sendKeys(value);

String value = "Gopi"; // this works
Driver.findElement(By.id("searchbox")).sendKeys(value);
```

Comment: please show the code that works, and code that fails.

Comment: can you use multiple words if you interact with the control manually?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant `HTML` and code trials please.

Comment: Please add a tag for the language you are using. It looks like Java but it's not clear. A link to the page would help a lot in understanding the problem and coming up with a solution.

Comment: What version of Selenium are you using?  Also what browser/ version, and what driver are you are executing this against would also help as well.